# What pose is best for to assume before hitting the ground for survival after failed parachute?

Tags: parachute, failures

The title says it all. Assuming one is falling down on a hard perpendicular surface after reaching terminal velocity, what pose provides the highest chances of survival?

My guess would be one of the poses on the picture below (sorry for crude sketch, notice the back is curved):

[image]

The rationale behind both is that a lot of energy gets dispersed through the limbs, which are the least vital part of the human body, and the general shape is a slight curve so that the victim rolls over as shown by the arrow, dissipating energy consequently up to his head. I'm not sure which of the two is better: the first one provides a little more protection for the head, but the right one can probably help save more vital organs in the torso in the same way legs do.

How liable is that?

Comment: Head first, then I don't have to deal with being paralyzed, massive hospital stays, rehabilitation, and life-long pain, not to mention the bills and inability to work.

Comment: @RonBeyer Not like you couldn't write books about how you survived the fall even paralyzed. Bet that'd sell

Comment: Maybe, but look at the ["famous fall survivors"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:Fall_survivors), don't think any of them died rich. My life insurance will probably pay more than a book deal. Another plus is if I get going fast enough they won't even have to bury me, I'll take care of that on the way down.

Comment: I believe the best "position" is straight up/down, feet first. You will break every bone in your body up to your back, but the goal is to keep your head from slamming down. The two positions you show will result in your head hitting the ground basically at the same speed. You also want to avoid your chest from slamming down (lots of important things in there along with pointy/fragile ribs).

Comment: Before we discard this, let's remember that few parachute failures are total failures (even among the tiny number that aren't dealt with by a reserve chute).

Comment: Grab your legs, bend over, and kiss your butt goodbye. Impacting at terminal velocity, your arteries will rupture and you'll bleed out, even if your skull isn't fractured.